# "Flake8 crashed!" Como solucionar?

Tags: python, atom

Tem uns dias que deixei o PyCharm do lado e passei a usar o Atom. Tudo funcionava tranquilamente e hoje, escrevi UMA LINHA em Python e apareceu a mensagem "flake8 crashed!".

Pensei que fosse falta de alguma dependência, mas não é. Alguém passando pelo mesmo problema ou sabe como resolver o mesmo?

Comment: Você poderia colocar aí qual foi alinha que causou o erro e o exemplo da mensagem que recebeu? Estive dando uma olhada no repositório do Github e tem umas issues sobre esse problema, mas precisaria de mais informações sobre o problema pra ajudar.

Comment: A linha que causou o erro foi a mais simples possível, foi essa:


jogadores =  int(input("Numero de jogadores "))


A cada letra que eu escrevia o Atom notificava esse erro.

Comment: Vc fez algum import?

Comment: O erro parou depois que desinstalei o flake8 e instalei novamente. Provavelmente foi um caso a parte, muita gente anda tendo esses erros. 

De qualquer forma, abram o Atom's Developer Tool pra ter mais informações.